# extending a class whose members are all static

Tags: java, static, extend

Does it ever make sense to extend a Java class whose methods are all static?

```
public class Parent{
  public static String child1(long numb){...};
  public static MyData child2(String str){...};
  ...
}

public class More extends Parent{...}
```

Comment: Of course it does, depending upon your needs

Comment: I can't see what the difference would be

Comment: @JGerulskis There is, since static methods cannot be overridden in the way instance methods can.

Comment: @hexafraction You cannot override static methods in any way. How would this be a benefit? Not being able to override a static method does not add any benefit but, rather a negative effect.

Comment: I never said there was a benefit. I said there was a difference, based on the wording of the comment I replied to.

Answer (score 0):

Few I think are mentioned below :

1. If all the methods in your class are static you can make the class a singleton it will save a lot of space.
2. You can use [template method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) very effectively, where some inheriting classes can define their specific things
3. For a class with no instance variables there is no need to synchronize. So your class can be accessed by N threads without you worrying to handle the concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Classes with only static member functions are often utility classes, i.e. they provide a grouping for functions that operate on other related objects. For example there is the the `Files` class which provides functions for working with `File` objects, and the apache commons `ArrayUtils` which provides tools for working with `T[]`.

The only sensible case where I've seen for extending a utility class is to reduce coupling with 3rd party utility classes. (Which in my opinion is a relatively weak reason).

Say you have some 3rd party `Foo` utilities that you use

```
public class YourFooUtilities {
  public static void makeAFooSing(Foo f) {...}
}
```

But you also need to have some internal `Foo` utilities, then you can do this:

```
public class MyFooUtilities extends YourFooUtilities {
    public static void makeAFooDance(Foo f) { ... }
    public static void makeAFooDanceAndSing(Foo f) { 
       makeAFooDance(f);
       makeAFooSing(f);
    }
}
```

Then your uses of `YourFooUtilities` can always be through `MyFooUtilites`, giving a layer of abstraction

```
static import MyFooUtilities.*;

public static class MainClass {    
  void doSomething() {
     Foo f = new Foo();
     makeFooDance(f);
     makeFooSing(f);
     makeAFooDanceAndSing(f);
  }
}
```

This makes your code (slightly) less tightly bound to the 3rd party code.